# Why is my variable corrupting as I pass it from Controller to Model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im annoyed.

I'm passing a variable from a Controller method to Method and somehow it is getting changed in the transfer.  Originally it was stupidly called `$id` .. so I thought there could be some variable interference going on.. but I have changed the name and the problem persists.

Can anyone tell me what may be happening?

Here is the code .. check my comments

```
public function firstFbLogin()
{
    ChromePhp::log('AJAX - first FB login');  // logs fine
    $username          = $this->input->post('username');
    $first_name        = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name         = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $facebookId        = $this->input->post('facebookId');
    $email             = $this->input->post('email');
    $third_party_id    = $this->input->post('third_party_id');
    $gender         = $this->input->post('gender');
    $this->Member_model->mFirstFbLogin($username, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $facebookId, $third_party_id, $gender);
            // here comes the issue..
    $idFromFbDooDaDay = $this->Member_model->mFetchIdFromFacebook($facebookId);
    ChromePhp::log("Id found and going out of ajax - firstFbLogin is ". $idFromFbDooDaDay); // <<< this logs 232 which is what I am expecting
    $this->Member_model->mCreateProfilePage($username, $first_name, $last_name, $idFromFbDooDaDay, $third_party_id, $gender);
    echo "TRUE";
}
```

But then over at my Member_model I have this (I'll edit out a bunch)

```
    public function mCreateProfilePage($username, $first_name, $last_name, $gender, $idFromFbDooDaDay, $third_party_id)
    {
        // lets create a 'profile.html' used for FB object interaction
        $this->load->helper('file');
        ChromePhp::log('Id coming into mCreateProfilePage is ' . $idFromFbDooDaDay);  // this logs as D0k9f7LxtjIHMhGnbn6UkhDk3ao  WTF!?!
        $data = "<html>\n";
        $data .= "<head prefix=\"og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# profile: http://ogp.me/ns/profile#\">\n";
        $data .= "<meta property=\"fb:app_id\" content=\"32xxxxxxxxxxxx6\" />\n"; // my APP ID
        $data .= "<meta property=\"og:type\"   content=\"profile\" />\n";  // stays profile
        $data .= "<meta property=\"og:url\"    content=\"www.MYSITE.com/profiles/id-".$idFromFbDooDaDay."\" />\n"; // put the URL
        $data .= "<meta property=\"og:image\"  content=\"https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png\" />\n";  // url to bigPic

 ... edit ...

        $file_path = 'profiles/id-' . $idFromFbDooDaDay . '.html';

        if (!write_file($file_path, $data))
        {
             ChromePhp::log('Problem writing profile');
        }
        else
        {
             ChromePhp::log('Profile written to '. $file_path);
        }
    }
```

So how is that `$idFromFbDooDaDay = 232` is turning into a 27-character nightmare of `$idFromFbDOoDaDay = D0k9f7LxtjIHMhGnbn6UkhDk3ao` over the span of a simple pass from Controller to Model?

It can't be variable interference.. and nothing else is touching the var, as far as I can see.  What is up?

Comment: Really the easiest way in these situations is using a debugging tool such as xDebug and following the path of the variable.
You can then see it in each step and see if it's being modified.
:)

Comment: I agree, but I am on OSX 10.6 and installation is tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// $this->Member_model->
mCreateProfilePage($username, $first_name, $last_name, $idFromFbDooDaDay, $third_party_id, $gender);
// public function 
mCreateProfilePage($username, $first_name, $last_name, $gender, $idFromFbDooDaDay, $third_party_id)
```

Your arguments aren't matching, that might be why :)